# Node.js deferred promisify + mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, deferred

Has anyone worked with the nodejs modules 'deferred' and 'mongoose'? I'm trying to get the deferred.promisify method to work on mongoose models' functions so I can chain them easily, but running into some troubles. Specifically, I'd like to promisify the `find` and `findById` functions so I can chain finding one document referenced by another document by ObjectID.

Here's what I've got: https://gist.github.com/3321827

However, this seems less than ideal since the `getAppPermissions` and `getApplication` functions seem to be little more than wrappers for the `find` and `findById` methods of the mongoose model.

I tried just passing the functions to promisify, but I get an error about `Object #<Object> has no method '_applyNamedScope'` which appears to be caused because `this` is no longer bound to the correct object. Perhaps I need to use underscore.bind? Has anyone had any success in this area, or should I just stick with what's working now?

Comment: Node/V8 implements `Function.prototype.bind`, so you don't need Underscore's bind; for example, `MyModel.find.bind(MyModel)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mariusz's answer was pretty close. Here's what ended up working for me in this particular case, hopefully others can learn from this:

```
// I put this in my model file so I didn't have to worry about repeating it
var userProto = mongoose.model('User');

userProto.pFind = deferred.promisify(userProto.find);
userProto.pFindOne = deferred.promisify(userProto.findOne);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't pass context to methods properly, right way to do this is to provide promisified versions of methods directly on Mongoose prototype:

```
// I assume that methods you're using are set on mongoose.Model,
// but be sure to check, maybe, they're using some other prototype (!)
var promisify = require('deferred').promisify;
var modelProto = mongoose.Model.prototype;
modelProto.pFind = promisify(modelProto.find);
modelProto.pFindById = promisify(modelProto.findById);

// After that you may use promisified methods directly:
app.get('/apps', requireLogin, function (req, res) {    
  AppPermissions.pFind({ user: req.user.id, valid: true })
    .map(function (permission) {
      return ApplicationRecord.pFindById(permission.application)(
        function (application) {
          application.permission = permisson;
          return application;
        }
      );
    }).end(function (applications) {
      res.render('applist', { applications: applications });
    }, null);
});
```

You can also refrain from polluting the prototype, and use methods indirectly:

```
var promisify = require('deferred').promisify;
var modelProto = mongoose.Model.prototype;
var pFind = promisify(modelProto.find);
var pFindById = promisify(modelProto.findById);

app.get('/apps', requireLogin, function (req, res) {    
  pFind.call(AppPermissions, { user: req.user.id, valid: true })
    .map(function (permission) {
      return pFindById.call(ApplicationRecord, permission.application)(
        function (application) {
          application.permission = permisson;
          return application;
        }
      );
    }).end(function (applications) {
      res.render('applist', { applications: applications });
    }, null);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this actually isn't the answer (see my own answer) but it definitely helped set me down the right direction!

Comment: Your answer is really same, I just wasn't sure how to get to *right* prototype object (didn't try to run the code). Anyway, great it's solved for you :)