# mongoose and q promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, deferred, promise, q

I'm working from the mongoose/q promises framework sample [here](https://gist.github.com/2660323), but seem to have some issues with the nfbind when trying to use findOne, mainly since the samples from the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) framework don't seem to match those in the gist.

My code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Q = require('q');

var user_schema = mongoose.Schema({username:String, last_touched:Date, app_ids:[String]});
var user = mongoose.model('user', user_schema);

exports.user = user;
exports.user.find = Q.nfbind(user.find);
exports.user.findOne = Q.nfbind(user.findOne);
```

If I call `user.findOne({username:'test'}).then(function(err, user) { ... }`, the user is always undefined.  If I remove the export and use the non-promise version with callbacks, I get the user.  I'm missing some special magic, but after looking at the code implementation, the example on from the Q github, and from the mongoose demo...  Nothing really jumps out.  Any ideas as to how I get to make a `findOne` work with Q?

I have also tried to set the `nfbind` functions up in the source rather than in the module, but to no avail.

Comment: Check also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912573/node-js-deferred-promisify-mongoose/11931908

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the methods you're nfbinding are methods of the `user` object, you need to `bind` them to that object before passing them to `nfbind` so that the `this` pointer is preserved when called.

This approach worked for me:

```
exports.user.find = Q.nfbind(user.find.bind(user));
exports.user.findOne = Q.nfbind(user.findOne.bind(user));
```

Comment: Tried that to - even exported as `searchByUsername` to make sure it wasn't a conflict in names.  Still get the same thing:  

    User from MongoDB:  undefined

Comment: Turns out I'm a wicked asshat and was mixing ideas: `user.findOne({'steam_username':username}).then(function (err, dbUser) { ... })`

Simply removed the `err` (duh, that's what .fail is for), and we were off to the races.  Durr!